# Create variable by combining text + another variable

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, ksh

Long story short, I'm trying to grep a value contained in the first column of a text file by using a variable.

Here's a sample of the script, with the grep command that doesn't work:

```
for ii in `cat list.txt`
do
    grep '^$ii' >outfile.txt
done
```

Contents of list.txt :

```
123,"first product",description,20.456789
456,"second product",description,30.123456
789,"third product",description,40.123456
```

If I perform `grep '^123' list.txt`, it produces the correct output...  Just the first line of list.txt.

If I try to use the variable (ie `grep '^ii' list.txt`) I get a "^ii command not found" error.  I tried to combine text with the variable to get it to work:

```
VAR1= "'^"$ii"'"
```

but the `VAR1` variable contained a carriage return after the `$ii` variable:

```
'^123
'
```

I've tried a laundry list of things to remove the cr/lr (ie sed & awk), but to no avail. There has to be an easier way to perform the grep command using the variable.  I would prefer to stay with the grep command because it works perfectly when performing it manually.

Comment: Also, show your desired output.

Comment: Thanks for the replies!  The desired output is just the first line of the file in this case.  Basically, I want the grep to search the first column and ignore the rest of the columns.  If a grep is used with no flags, each line of the file will be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have things mixed in the command `grep '^ii' list.txt`. The character `^` is for the beginning of the line and a `$` is for the value of a variable.
When you want to grep for 123 in the variable ii at the beginning of the line, use

```
ii="123"
grep "^$ii" list.txt
```

(You should use double quotes here)
Good moment for learning good habits: Continue in variable names in lowercase (well done) and use curly braces (don't harm and are needed in other cases) :

```
ii="123"
grep "^${ii}" list.txt
```

Now we both are forgetting something: Our `grep` will also match 
`1234,"4-digit product",description,11.1111`. Include a `,` in the grep:

```
ii="123"
grep "^${ii}," list.txt
```

And how did you get the "^ii command not found" error ? I think you used backquotes (old way for nesting a command, better is `echo "example: $(date)"`) and you wrote

```
grep `^ii` list.txt # wrong !
```

Comment: Thanks Walter, that did the trick!  in addition to your response, I found that I needed to perform a dos2unix on the list.txt file because it was generated in Windows.  Thank you to everyone who replied!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
# Read every character before the first comma into the variable ii.
while IFS=, read ii rest; do
    # Echo the value of ii. If these values are what you want, you're done; no
    # need for grep.
    echo "ii = $ii"
    # If you want to find something associated with these values in another
    # file, however, you can grep the file for the values. Use double quotes so
    # that the value of $ii is substituted in the argument to grep.
    grep "^$ii" some_other_file.txt >outfile.txt
done <list.txt
```